# Es posible extraer información ( constantes, variables... ) de otro archivo en JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Necesito extraer el valor de una constante de un archivo de JS "externo".
Lo que quiero lograr es un script de "ayuda" que al invocarlo llame el valor de X tema:

```
Usuario: help (profile)
BOT: "Extrae de la constante de 'profile.js' llamada "info" el valor y  lo devuelve"
```

Decidme si se precisa de alguna aclaración, al no saber como lograr este proceso se me hace difícil pedir ayuda sobre algo que desconozco. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Y que es lo que tienes en profile.js? Sólo una colección de variables con un valor? Porque si ese fuera el caso te conviene que profile sea un JSON

Comment: Lo que tengo en profile.js en un script que hace uso de canvas para dibujar una hoja de perfil. Lo que quiero lograr es que cada script tenga una función de info la cual pueda ser llamada desde el script de ayuda y asi lograr una línea de información.

Comment: ¿El fichero estaría en tu documento HTML declarado?

Comment: No existe un fichero html, hago uso de nodejs + la api de discord (Básicamente, un bot de discord[Una red social] )